# How to reverse particular string in an input string and return the whole string, with reversed part?

Tags: python, string, text-processing, text-parsing

I am having problems with what was said in the title. Basically I am given sentences which contain addresses - I am to reverse only the address in the sentence and return the string. I can reverse the address fine but I am having troubles returning the whole string. My code: ( edit :now corrected):

```
def problem3(searchstring):
    """
    Garble Street name.

    :param searchstring: string
    :return: string
    """
    flag = 0
    output = ""
    #each word is considered in loop
    for i in searchstring.split():

        if i.endswith('.'): #if the word ends with .
            flag = 0
            stype = i
            output += " " + stype
        elif flag == 1: #if the flag is 1
            #street =
            output += " " + i[::-1]
        elif i.isdigit(): #if the word is digit
            flag =1
            #num = i
            output += i
        else:
            output += i + " "
    #address = num + " " + street + " " + stype
    return output
```

Comment: You might want to use a regex for this, like [this one](https://ideone.com/TC6EPL), `re.sub(r'(\d+\s+)(.*?)(\s+\S+\.)(?!\S)', lambda x: f"{x.group(1)}{x.group(2)[::-1]}{x.group(3)}", text)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def problem3(searchstring):
    """
    Garble Street name.

    :param searchstring: string
    :return: string
    """
    flag = 0
    street = ""
    stri=""
    #each word is considered in loop
    for i in searchstring.split():
        if i.endswith('.'): #if the word ends with .
            flag = 0
            stype = i
            continue
        if flag == 1: #if the flag is 1
            street = street + " " + i[::-1]
            continue
        if i.isdigit(): #if the word is digit
            flag =1
            num = i
            continue
        stri=stri+' '+i
    address =stri+" "+ num + " " + street + " " + stype
    return address
```

Then if you call the function:

```
print(problem3('The EE building is at 465 Northwestern Ave.'))
print(problem3('Meet me at 201 South First St. at noon'))
```

output will be

```
The EE building is at 465  nretsewhtroN Ave.                                                                                                      
Meet me at at noon 201  htuoS tsriF St.
```

Comment: Thank you but theres one small problem - it always includes a space at the beginning of the output string - how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'if' several times you can use the below code or you can use continue also:

```
def problem3(searchstring):
    """
    Garble Street name.

    :param searchstring: string
    :return: string
    """
    flag = 0
    address = ""
    #each word is considered in loop
    for i in searchstring.split():

        if i.endswith('.'): #if the word ends with .
            flag = 0
            stype = i
            address += " " + stype
        elif flag == 1: #if the flag is 1
            #street =
            address += " " + i[::-1]
        elif i.isdigit(): #if the word is digit
            flag =1
            #num = i
            address += i
        else:
            address += i + " "
    #address = num + " " + street + " " + stype
    return address
print(problem3('The EE building is at 465 Northwestern Ave.'))
```